# How do I use php in sublimetext3?

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I can't seem to use `php` on `sublimetext3`

I've tried this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["PHP", "$file"]
}
```

Saving this under `C:\Users\  \AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`

But when i try to execute this:

```
<?php

echo"It worked"

?>
```

I get this error:

```
 [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: You need to also install `php` on your machine and then either add the location that the php binary is in to your system `PATH` or modify the build system to specify the path directly (video covering problems similar to this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WLV87B63SY) if you're interested)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a server. This can be done with Apache or NGINX or even IIS, or with a built-in server, but recommend xampp:

http://learningcn.com/SublimeServer/

https://www.apachefriends.org/